# How to add a condition in "ON" cause of "LEFT JOIN" in PonyORM

Tags: python-3.x, ponyorm

I want to run the following query in PonyORM.

```
SELECT af.AppFormID, af.AppFormTitle, ra.CreateGrant, ra.ReadGrant, ra.UpdateGrant, ra.DeleteGrant, ra.PrintGrant
FROM public.appforms as af left join public.roleaccesses as ra 
on af.appformid = ra.appformid and ra.roleid = 2
```

if you see the last part of the code, I added a condition in "ON" cause.

I tried to write the following code in python.

```
query= orm.left_join((af.AppFormID, af.AppFormTitle, ra.CreateGrant, ra.ReadGrant, ra.UpdateGrant, ra.DeleteGrant, ra.PrintGrant) for af in AppForms for ra in af.RoleAccess if ra.RoleID.RoleID == id)
```

But, "if" is known as "WHERE" cause. How can I solve this problem?

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current version of PonyORM (0.7.6) does not support additional conditions in LEFT JOIN clause. But I agree that this is a useful feature.

Please add a new issue here: https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues

I do not guarantee that it will be implemented quickly, but eventually we will add it.

Until this, you need to write a raw SQL query:

```
role_id = 2

rows = db.select("""
    SELECT af.AppFormID, af.AppFormTitle,
           ra.CreateGrant, ra.ReadGrant,
           ra.UpdateGrant, ra.DeleteGrant, ra.PrintGrant
    FROM public.appforms as af
      LEFT JOIN public.roleaccesses as ra
        ON af.appformid = ra.appformid and ra.roleid = $role_id
""")
```